# Navigation bar no longer hides in some games since Android 11

Tags: google-pixel, google-pixel-2, navigation-bar, android-11

Since updating to Android 11, I've noticed some games I used to play no longer hide the navigation bar as expected.  Some apps, however, work as expected.

One game in question I have is Carmageddon, with the navigation bar visible on the right.

I have tried:

- Checking for updates (no update since 2017)
- Swiping from top, left, right, bottom
- Restarting phone

Is there a way to restore the original behavior where this game would be able to hide the navigation bar?

[image: Carmageddon with navigation bar visible on right]